# C++ build memory usage profiling

Tags: c++, cmake, build

I'm working on a big project, there are complex templates.
1 build worker can take up to 2-3Gb of memory building application, and 4-5Gb building tests.
I want to find which places have the biggest memory usage and solve It.

How to profile C++ build?

Comment: Is this really a big problem? What are your requirements for building the application? Sure you can probably lower the memory requirements, but then that will most likely slow down the build process. You can get a fast build, *or* a memory efficient build, but not both.

Comment: [Finding build bottlenecks with C++ Build Insights](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/finding-build-bottlenecks-with-cpp-build-insights/)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The problem is that with 32Gb memory I can build tests with 4 workers, instead of 12, which makes development slower. And sometimes memory is full and the computer must be rebooted.

Comment: @user7860670 Do you know an analog for Linux?

Comment: No, i don't. Also i should mention that it is really a big problem on linux+gcc combo because gcc is notorious for poor handling of ram-related build issues (basically SEGFAULTs all of it sudden in insufficient memory situation).